# A difficult master theorem problem

Tags: time-complexity, master-theorem

Consider the function $B:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
B(n) = \begin{cases}
         1 &\text{if $n\le 2$}\\
         B\left(\left\lceil\frac{n}{\log_2n}\right\rceil \right)+n&\text{if $n\ge 3$}
       \end{cases}
$$

I'm having a lot of trouble with this question. I tried substituting things like $n=2^m$, but that didn't really help... My exam is tomorrow... Can someone help, please?

Comment: Please include all relevant information in the body of the question.  Use Latex to typeset equations.  Give attribution to the source of all problems.  Show us what you have tried, where you got stuck, and what techniques you know that might be relevant; then see if you can articulate a specific question about your approach or attempts.  This is not a place where you can upload a copy of your exercise and we'll solve it for you.

Comment: Hint: the Master Theorem doesn't apply, because $\frac{1}{\log_2 n}$ is not a constant. Try using the tree method.

Answer (score 0):

We'll show that $B(n)=O(n)$ first and provide a hint about showing that $B(n)=\Omega(n)$. In both proofs, the $n/\lg n$ term is the problem, so we'll find suitable bounds for that. In both proofs, we'll suppress the ceilings around the argument.

$\mathbf{B(n)=O(n)}$:

We'll show inductively that $B(n)\le 2n$ for all $n\ge 512$. The base case is easy: 
$$
B(512)=935\le 1024=2\cdot512
$$
Now assume that $B(k)\le 2k$ for all $512\le k < n$. Then we'll have $n/\lg n\le n/9$ and so
$$\begin{align}
B(n) &= 3B(n/\lg n)+n &\text{by definition}\\
 &\le 3B(n/9)+n &\text{since $B$ is increasing}\\
 &\le 3\cdot 2(n/9)+n &\text{by assumption}\\
 &=\frac{2n}{3}+n\\
 &=\frac{5n}{3}<2n&\text{as required}
\end{align}$$

$\mathbf{B(n)=\Omega(n)}$:

In a similar way, we can show that $B(n)\ge n$ for all $n>2$, using the fact that $n/\lg n\ge 1$. This, along with the previous result establishes that $B(n)=\Theta(n)$.